# Reputation lost

Tags: support, reputation

I lost reputation worth 30 points because 'user was removed'.Why should my reputation be lost if someone else's account is deleted.I had give correct answer to the question for which I had initially gained reputation. Why did this happen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [user was removed](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1289/)

Comment: Soham: You need the moderator concerned to answer this question. But I expect it's because there's dishonest voting going on, by sockpuppets. That's where some people log on with a different userid and vote for themselves, or for others in their "gang of trolls". Hence you see some vapid answers with massive upvote scores. Then when moderators clean up, there's some collateral damage, like to your reputation. Here, I've just given you an upvote to soften the blow.

Comment: You lost 30 reuutation points on June 12th, 2015, at 23:06 o'clock. It seems John Duffield's hunch is right on the money. See my comment in [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6855/2451) meta post.